# Quartus Error (10028) with memory

Tags: verilog, drivers, quartus

My goal is to form this code with Quartus, but the problem is I don't know how to fix the problem.
I've tried to know what Error 10028 means, but I cant figure out how to work with it.
Can someone teach me how to fix it or if there's a way to bypass it?

```
module mem (r_wb,addr,d,q);
input r_wb;//0write 1read
input [7:0] addr;
input [7:0 ] d;
output [7:0] q;
reg [7:0] q;
reg [7:0] mem_bank [0:255];
always @(r_wb)
 if (r_wb)  q=mem_bank[addr];
 else  mem_bank[addr]=d;
always @(addr)
 if (r_wb)  q=mem_bank[addr];
 else  mem_bank[addr]=d;
always @(d)
 if (r_wb)  q=mem_bank[addr];
 else  mem_bank[addr]=d;
endmodule
```

Comment: I figured out myself...

Comment: module mem (clk,r_wb,addr,d,q);
input clk;
input r_wb;//0write 1read
input [7:0] addr;
input [7:0 ] d;
output [7:0] q;
reg [7:0] q;
reg [7:0] mem_bank [0:255];
always @(posedge clk)
     if (r_wb)  q=mem_bank[addr];
     else  mem_bank[addr]=d;
endmodule

Comment: If you figured this out, post your solution as an answer.

Comment: It is recommended to use `always@*` for combinational blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you put in your comment is mostly correct in the fact that you do need a clocking signal. However you should be using non-blocking assignment (`<=`).

I would recommend changing your model header to ANSI style which has been around since 2001. The non-ANSI style required `q` the be identified three times; port list, direction, type. ANSI style compacts it. Non-ANSI is good to understand because a lot of synthesizers and code generators still use it by default. But any modern simulator or synthesizer will accept ANSI style as input.

```
module mem (
  input clk, 
  input r_wb, //0write 1read
  input [7:0] addr, 
  input [7:0 ] d, 
  output reg [7:0] q) ;
  reg [7:0] mem_bank [0:255];

  always @(posedge clk)
    if (r_wb) q<=mem_bank[addr];
    else mem_bank[addr]<=d;
endmodule
```